# "ping: bad address" on DNS entry, IP is fine

Tags: dns, ping, openwrt, bind

I have two centos/bind dns servers -

```
masterdns.internal.example.com
secondarydns.internal.example.com
```

if configuring a desktop I can assign the DNS addresses for each and can successfully ping internal servers on my network using the fqdn.

The problem is from my openwrt router I am unable to ping anything but the IP address of a server.  I have a funny feeling it's because of dnsmasq is muddying the issue but I've tried disabling it and hasn't solved the issue.

Seems like it's having issues routing to the DNS servers even though I've specified them in my interface.

on my openwrt router I have the lan setup with the following info

```
ipaddr - 10.77.1.100
netmask - 255.255.255.0
gateway - 10.77.1.10
custom dns - 10.77.1.50, 10.77.1.51
```

under dhcp and dns

```
local domain - internal.example.com
DNS forwardings - 10.77.1.50, 10.77.1.51
```

From my openwrt router (with the ip of 10.77.1.100) I can do a ping to 10.77.1.50 but I cannot ping to any of the following -

```
masterdns
masterdns.internal
masterdns.internal.example
masterdns.internal.example.com
```

All return the same failure `"ping: bad address 'masterdns'"`

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough details here to help. Describe all relevant bits involved, where they are located, how traffic is routed to them, etc. What are you referring to by "the IP address of a server"?

Comment: @EEAA - provided more info hope it's enough.

Comment: OK, you're trying to troubleshoot DNS issues with ping. That's not going to work out well for you. If you're troubleshooting DNS, use DNS tools (dig, host, nslookup, etc.). From what I can tell, this question has nothing to do with ICMP pings.

Comment: thnx.  dig and host don't work (not installed can look at doing later if possible).  nslookup gives `Server: 127.0.0.1, Addres1: 127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: [ping: bad address](https://thalif.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/ping-bad-address/).